# What causes the following linking error with the boost c++ libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cygwin

Hi I get a linking error when compiling my program with the gcc compiler on cygwin. The first picture is a simple sample program from the boost filesystem libraries tutorial page where I have included filesystem.hpp in the boost folder. Beneath that is the picture of my linker error when I try to compile with the following command:

```
g++ -I C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0 -I C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++Dep/eigen-3.4.0 -L C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0/stage/lib test.cpp -o ser
```

Here I try to compile my program test.cpp with the eigen and boost libraries and set the includer path that they tell me to set as the path after I have built the library with b2.exe. I have also linked to the lib files for boost. I have also tried linking to the different filesystem lib files specifically. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using std::cout;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    cout << "Usage: tut3 path\n";
    return 1;
  }

  path p (argv[1]);

  try
  {
    if (exists(p))
    {
      if (is_regular_file(p))
        cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

      else if (is_directory(p))
      {
        cout << p << " is a directory containing:\n";

        for (directory_entry& x : directory_iterator(p))
          cout << "    " << x.path() << '\n';
      }
      else
        cout << p << " exists, but is not a regular file or directory\n";
    }
    else
      cout << p << " does not exist\n";
  }

  catch (const filesystem_error& ex)
  {
    cout << ex.what() << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you build boost using the same compiler inside cygwin? msvc binaries will not work.

Comment: Yes, I ran the bootstrap file with gcc and then b2.exe inside cygwin

Comment: You are not providing the boost file system library to the compiler (just the directory where it can be found). Look in the directory `C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0/stage/lib` look for a boost and fileystem asa library and add to the command line above

Comment: I have tried that. That is what I wrote in my question

Comment: I see in your question you did not specify the actual library to link. You told the compiler where the headers are and the linker where the libraries are but you did not link to the filesystem library. It's not going to do that automatically like it would in msvc with the #pragma comment(lib, libname.lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a linking error when compiling my program

No, you don't. You are getting a linking error when *linking* your program, not when compiling it.

The reason: you didn't supply the library (`-L C:/Users/....` tells the linker where to search for libraries; not which libraries to link). Your command line should look something like:

```
g++ -I ... -L ... test1.cpp -o ser -lboost_filesystem
```

Comment: I have just tried doing what you said, with linking the specific library but I still get `cannot find -llibboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_77.lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`, here is the command I tried: `g++ -I C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0 -L C:/Users/Ejer/Desktop/c++/c++Dep/boost_1_77_0/stage/lib/ -l libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_77.lib main.cpp -o ser`

Comment: @SamuelCadell library should go _after_ `main.cpp`, not before it. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking. Also you want `-lboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_77`, not `-l libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_77.lib`